# Where do I place ESLint rules/exceptions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, eslint

I am following [this](https://medium.com/technoetics/create-a-developer-portfolio-using-reactjs-d34ea1bfb18e) React JS Tutorial.

It's throwing some `jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid` errors.

I found a hack to add the following code to what I am assuming is a `.eslintrc` file:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [ "error", {
      "components": [ "Link" ],
      "specialLink": [ "to" ]
    }]
  }
}
```

But I have no idea where it is or if I should create it in the `src` folder. Do I add anything to `package.json` file?

Comment: In the root level of your project

Comment: This can be in the form of an .eslintrc.* file or an eslintConfig field in a package.json file, both of which ESLint will look for and read automatically, or you can specify a configuration file on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

This can be in the form of an `.eslintrc.*` file or an `eslintConfig` field in a `package.json` file, both of which ESLint will look for and read automatically, or you can specify a configuration file on the command line.

In package.json:

```
{
    "name": "mypackage",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "eslintConfig": {
        "rules": {
            "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [ "error", {
            "components": [ "Link" ],
            "specialLink": [ "to" ]
       }]
     }
   }
}
```

This needs to be at root level of the project

Comment: It doesn't work, it still shows errors in the console.

Comment: Can you try adding Adding `"jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0` to `.eslintrc.json`